# Android : Realm database delete all the records after first N records from the database

Tags: android, sqlite, realm, realm-mobile-platform, android-database

I've integrated Realm android to my project.
I want to keep my table restriction to store max 100 records. If any new records come then check for if its limit increases to 100 then It should delete those records (101..N). The table should contain the last 100 records only.

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic way of doing this. But if you add a timestamp in your model class (say, `created`), you could add a [listener](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest#realm-notifications) and delete the old object. Something like:

`realmListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(Realm realm) {
        RealmResults<YourClass> objs;
        int nObjsToDelete;
        objs = realm.where(YourClass.class).sort(created).findAll();
        nObjsToDelete = objs.size()-100;
        objs.limit(nObjectToDelete).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
    }
};
realm.addChangeListener(realmListener);`

Comment: Can you help me group delete query instead of doing delete within loop?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try it out.